# Java Application of Arrays and For-loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

***Here's the question:***

Write a program that that reads ten integers into an array and 
computes the sum of the array of values, except for the largest one. 
(Hint: Find the difference between the sum and the largest value of the 
array)

---

***And this is the given sample that you have to achieve:***

```
Please input 10 integers: 3 4 1 9 2 10 8 6 7 5
Sum without the max: 45
```

---

***The program beneath is my personal attempt:***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumWithoutMax {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);       
    System.out.print("Please input 10 integers: ");
    int [] x = new int [10];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    int max = x[0];
    int sum = 0-max;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if(x[i] > max) {
            max = x[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + x[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Sum without the max: " +sum);
}

}
```

---

***And the result of my attempt is just like this:***

```
Please input 10 integers: 3 4 1 9 2 10 8 6 7 5 
Sum without the max: 52
```

---

**What's wrong with the program actually? Can somebody help me find it out and teach me how to solve it? Thanks:)**

Comment: Guys, firstly thank you for all of your detailed and brilliant answers for my question. But please don't vote "down" for this post because I have only been getting in touch with Java for more or less a week, so it's reasonable for me to ask these kinds of nonsense questions, I guess. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with your code is you are subtrating `x[0]` value (which assume max at initial).

---

Even You can achive the with single for-loop.

```
int max = x[0];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i] > max) {
        max = x[i];
    }
    sum = sum + x[i];
}
sum -=max;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting the maximum before you know it. Move `int sum = 0-max;` after the loop that seeks it.

Comment: By the way, for the sake of readability it should be either `sum = -max;` (worse way) or `sum -= max;` at the end (better one)

Answer (score 1):

The first sum=0-max; is wrong because max is not known yet. You need to do it after you find the max.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + x[i];
}

sum -= max;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  int sum = -max;
```

When loop find the maximum number.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
int sum = -max;
```

*after* the loop that finds the max.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumWithoutMax {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);       
System.out.print("Please input 10 integers: ");
int [] x = new int [10];
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i] = in.nextInt();
}

int max = x[0];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i] > max) {
        max = x[i];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + x[i];
}

sum = sum - max;
System.out.println("Sum without the max: " +sum);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer in JAVA 8 :

```
Integer sum = Arrays.asList(3,4,1,9,2,10,8,6,7,5).stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).skip(1).reduce(
               0,(a, b) -> a + b);
```